# How to replace nulls with values from another row by ID in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe.

```
+------+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------------------+----+------------------+------+-----+-----------+
|prodid|       snbr|              A|       B|        C|                 D|   E|                 F|     G|    H|          I|
+------+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------------------+----+------------------+------+-----+-----------+
| 10510|          0|           null|    null|      750|              null|null|              null| 48.72| 3.15|Napa Valley|
| 10510|          1|     California|       1|     null|Cabernet Sauvignon| Red|Cabernet Sauvignon|  null| null|       null|
| 26619|          0|      Australia|       1|      750|Cabernet Sauvignon| Red|Cabernet Sauvignon| 2.695| 2.95|       null|
| 26619|          1|           null|    null|     null|            Shiraz|null|    Syrah / Shiraz|  null| null|       null|
+------+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------------------+----+------------------+------+-----+-----------+
```

I want this dataframe

```
+------+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------------------+----+------------------+------+-----+-----------+
|prodid|       snbr|              A|       B|        C|                 D|   E|                 F|     G|    H|          I|
+------+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------------------+----+------------------+------+-----+-----------+
| 10510|          0|     California|       1|      750|Cabernet Sauvignon| Red|Cabernet Sauvignon| 48.72| 3.15|Napa Valley|
| 10510|          1|     California|       1|      750|Cabernet Sauvignon| Red|Cabernet Sauvignon| 48.72| 3.15|Napa Valley|
| 26619|          0|      Australia|       1|      750|Cabernet Sauvignon| Red|Cabernet Sauvignon| 2.695| 2.95|       null|
| 26619|          1|      Australia|       1|      750|            Shiraz| Red|    Syrah / Shiraz| 2.695| 2.95|       null|
+------+-----------+---------------+--------+---------+------------------+----+------------------+------+-----+-----------+
```

I want to copy the none null rows from one row to another in a dynamic way. Without using specific column names. Using prodid and snbr is ok.

TBH Im lost. I thinking i may have rethink how i got here. Sorry, I don't have any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution,I have taken only three cols A,B,F to cover diff cases but this will work any no of cols and any no of rows. Basically finding the max gives the non null in each group of "prodid" and joining with "prodid" and "snbr" gives the desired output.

*But this doesn't work if in a group for a col more than one distinct value is there and also null value exists. You can tweak this solution according to your req.*

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(10510, 0, 'California', None,None),(10510, 1, None,1,'Cabernet Sauvignon'),(10510, 2, None,None,None),
     (26619, 1, None,1,'Cabernet Sauvignon'),(26619, 2, 'Australia',None,'Cabernet Sauvignon'),(26619, 3, 'Australia',1,'Syrah / Shiraz')
    ], ["prodid", "snbr", "A","B","F"])

df_not_nulls = df.groupBy(
    F.col("prodid")
).agg(  *(F.max(c).alias(c)
      for c in df.columns if c!= 'prodid')
)

df.join(df_not_nulls,"prodid").select(*[F.coalesce(df[c],df_not_nulls[c]).alias(c) for c in df.columns]).show()
```

which results

```
+------+----+----------+---+------------------+
|prodid|snbr|         A|  B|                 F|
+------+----+----------+---+------------------+
| 10510|   0|California|  1|Cabernet Sauvignon|
| 10510|   1|California|  1|Cabernet Sauvignon|
| 10510|   2|California|  1|Cabernet Sauvignon|
| 26619|   1| Australia|  1|Cabernet Sauvignon|
| 26619|   2| Australia|  1|Cabernet Sauvignon|
| 26619|   3| Australia|  1|    Syrah / Shiraz|
+------+----+----------+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Almost but fails when the sequence number grows. Sometimes there may be more than 2 rows for a prod id. You're right it does work for the input and output given. Thank you

Comment: I dont understand where it checks for nulls??

Comment: coalesce function returns the non null value.